# Idiom for scientific charts & graphs on a subject

Tags: idiom-requests

I have many charts & graphs which represent a single topic from a diverse points of views, using various parameters.

For example, on the subject of `Building a House`:

- Graph which represent the cost (`$`) against the time
- Graph which represent the cost (`$`) against the eco-friendly level of the house
- Graph which represent the number of rooms against the work which needs to be invested per-week in order to clean them.

and many more.

In the example, the parameters are: cost, time, eco-friendly level, number of rooms etc.

How do I define this set of graphs in a couple of words?
Is it called "statistics"? "Cross-section data"?

Comment: In this specific case I think you can call them:'Construction estimate data'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might refer to *statistical charts*, *cost charts*, *cost graphics*, etc.

The sense of *chart* used here is, from [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chart#Noun), “A systematic non-narrative presentation of data”, which encompasses tables, diagrams, graphs, etc.

From [en.wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics), examples of graphics include “photographs, drawings, Line Art, graphs, diagrams, typography, numbers, symbols, geometric designs, maps, engineering drawings, or other images”.

Wikipedia also indicates the term *[infographic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infographic)* is in use to refer to  “graphic visual representations of information, data or knowledge intended to present complex information quickly and clearly”.